# Android Camera2 API RAW capture with flash

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, camera-flash, camera-api

I tried to take flashed images and RAW with camera2 API and save JPEG and DNG files. When I make first shoot, the result image (jpeg) is black. On second shot everything is fine! I make photos in completely dark room. Flash fires for both shots. And each time flash fires twice (precapture and capture).

Also similar issue happens, when I try to capture just JPEG image (without RAW) and exposure is set to 0.

Here is code of creation of capture requests:

```
public static void CreateRequests(final int format) throws CameraAccessException
{
    final boolean isRAWCapture = (format == CameraController.RAW);

    stillRequestBuilder = HALv3.getInstance().camDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
    precaptureRequestBuilder = HALv3.getInstance().camDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
    rawRequestBuilder = HALv3.getInstance().camDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
    if (format == CameraController.YUV_RAW)
    {
        stillRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE, CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE_OFF);
        stillRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE, CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE_OFF);

        precaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE, CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE_OFF);
        precaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE, CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE_OFF);
    } else if (isRAWCapture)
    {
        stillRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE, CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE_HIGH_QUALITY);
        stillRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE,
                CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE_HIGH_QUALITY);

        precaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE, CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE_HIGH_QUALITY);
        precaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE,
                CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE_HIGH_QUALITY);
        rawRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE, CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE_OFF);
        rawRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE, CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE_OFF);
    } else
    {
        stillRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE, CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE_HIGH_QUALITY);
        stillRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE,
                CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE_HIGH_QUALITY);

        precaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE, CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE_HIGH_QUALITY);
        precaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE,
                CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE_HIGH_QUALITY);
    }

    stillRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.TONEMAP_MODE, CaptureRequest.TONEMAP_MODE_HIGH_QUALITY);
    precaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.TONEMAP_MODE, CaptureRequest.TONEMAP_MODE_HIGH_QUALITY);
    if (isRAWCapture)
        rawRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.TONEMAP_MODE, CaptureRequest.TONEMAP_MODE_HIGH_QUALITY);
    if ((zoomLevel > 1.0f) && (format != CameraController.YUV_RAW))
    {
        zoomCropCapture = getZoomRect(zoomLevel, activeRect.width(), activeRect.height());
        stillRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, zoomCropCapture);
        precaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, zoomCropCapture);
        if (isRAWCapture)
            rawRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, zoomCropCapture);
    }

    int focusMode = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainScreen.getMainContext()).getInt(
            CameraController.isFrontCamera() ? MainScreen.sRearFocusModePref : MainScreen.sFrontFocusModePref, -1);
    stillRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, focusMode);
    precaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, focusMode);
    if (isRAWCapture)
        rawRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, focusMode);

    if (format == CameraController.JPEG)
    {
        stillRequestBuilder.addTarget(MainScreen.getJPEGImageReader().getSurface());
    } else if (format == CameraController.YUV || format == CameraController.YUV_RAW)
    {
        stillRequestBuilder.addTarget(MainScreen.getYUVImageReader().getSurface());
    } else if (format == CameraController.RAW)
    {
        rawRequestBuilder.addTarget(MainScreen.getRAWImageReader().getSurface());
        stillRequestBuilder.addTarget(MainScreen.getJPEGImageReader().getSurface());
    }
    precaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(MainScreen.getPreviewYUVImageReader().getSurface());


    int flashMode = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainScreen.getMainContext()).getInt(
            MainScreen.sFlashModePref, -1);

    Integer previewFlash = null;
    if (flashMode == CameraParameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF) {
        previewFlash = CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_OFF;
    } else if (flashMode == CameraParameters.FLASH_MODE_SINGLE) {
        previewFlash = CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_SINGLE;
    } else if (flashMode == CameraParameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH) {
        previewFlash = CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH;
    }
    HALv3.stillRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, previewFlash);
    HALv3.precaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, previewFlash);
    HALv3.rawRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, previewFlash);

    if(flashMode == CameraParameters.FLASH_MODE_SINGLE || flashMode == CameraParameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO || flashMode == CameraParameters.FLASH_MODE_REDEYE)
    {
        if(flashMode == CameraParameters.FLASH_MODE_SINGLE)
            flashMode = CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH;
        else if(flashMode == CameraParameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO )
            flashMode = CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH;
        else
            flashMode = CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH_REDEYE;

        HALv3.stillRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        HALv3.stillRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, flashMode);

        HALv3.precaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        HALv3.precaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, flashMode);

        HALv3.rawRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        HALv3.rawRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, flashMode);
    }
}
```

and capture methods:

```
public static int captureImageWithParamsHALv3Simple(final int nFrames, final int format, final int[] pause,
        final int[] evRequested, final int[] gain, final long[] exposure, final boolean resInHeap,
        final boolean playShutter)
{

    int requestID;
    try
    {
        requestID = HALv3.getInstance().mCaptureSession.capture(stillRequestBuilder.build(), stillCaptureCallback,
                null);

        if (isRAWCapture)
            HALv3.getInstance().mCaptureSession.capture(rawRequestBuilder.build(), stillCaptureCallback, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;

}

public static int captureImageWithParamsHALv3(final int nFrames, final int format, final int[] pause,
        final int[] evRequested, final int[] gain, final long[] exposure, final boolean resInHeap,
        final boolean playShutter)
{
    int requestID = -1;

    try
    {
        CreateRequests(format);

        precaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER,
                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER_START);
        requestID = HALv3.getInstance().mCaptureSession.capture(precaptureRequestBuilder.build(),
                new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request,
                            TotalCaptureResult result)
                    {
                        precaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER,
                                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER_IDLE);

                        captureImageWithParamsHALv3Simple(nFrames, format, pause, evRequested, gain, exposure,
                                resInHeap, playShutter);
                    }
                }, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "setting up still image capture request failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    return requestID;
}
enter code here
```

Also you may see full code of project here: https://github.com/almalence/OpenCamera

And camera2 part:
https://github.com/almalence/OpenCamera/blob/master/src/com/almalence/opencam/cameracontroller/HALv3.java

Comment: Hi, did you figure that out ? I'm reaching the same problem :/

Comment: @gbero I don't remember exactly, if I fixed it. But you can see https://github.com/almalence/OpenCamera project. For now it captures normal image in dark conditions with flashlight. Look at Camera2Controller.java, it contains code related to Camera2 API